# help identifying marine item found on beach

Tags: species-identification, species, marine-biology

Need help identifying this hard waxy egg like item found on beach in Destin, FL (USA).  It feels waxy and semi hard. Also smells like squid or real fishy. it is also semi transparent with dark tan looking tie on inside

[image]
[image]
[image]

Larger versions of pictures shown below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the approximate size and any additional relevant info. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You've found a [swim bladder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swim_bladder). Swim bladders are largely made from collagen, so when they're dried out on beaches they feel tough and rigid.

Swim bladders differ in shape between species. As an example, the swim bladders of [oyster toadfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oyster_toadfish) are [similarly-shaped](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rspb.2016.1094) to the one you have found, but that general shape isn't uncommon, so it could have come from many other species.